# Mongo deepFind?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I Have a mongoDB that contains data in unknown structure, and I want to find all the documents that has a specific BsonElement. Can I do it without the knowledge about the documents structure?

For example, if the documents look like this (and I don't know that) can I find all the documents that has `"DBType":"MSSQL"`?

There is somting like `collection.deepFind(QueryDocument);`?

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("528fe1602feaa3231c784d92"),
   "CurrentJobs" : {
       "_t" : "sqQueryJob",
       "IsDone" : false,
       "ExecuteTime" : ISODate("2013-11-22T22:57:35.733Z"),
       "Result" : { },
       "DB" : {
           "DBType" : "MSSQL",
           "Name" : "Data",
           "Host" : ".",
           "ServiceName" : "DataBase",
           "Port" : "1521",
       },
       "QueryResult" : null,
       "Query" : "."
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to find all documents where either the top level document, or any of the embedded documents might match some query.

Comment: @idbentley I want to find all the top level documents, that any of there child-documents (or child of child [of child ...]) has the element "X:Y"

Comment: MongoDB has no wildcard like the one you are describing.  There is a SERVER ticket quite similar, but it hasn't been implemented: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-267.

Comment: @idbentley So the only way is to make a recursive method, walk into the struction and use reguler find()? ouch...

Comment: You could say that.  I would suggest that you should probably change your schema if that's an option.  Remember that with MongoDB, you need to try to design your schema for your queries.

Comment: when you write the document, you could have an indexed array of distinct attributes you'd need to search on. you can also index an array of key/values so you can use a single index to find a key in an array like [ {k:'DB.DBType',v:'MSSQL'}, {'DB.Child.Child.DB.DBType',v':'MSSQL'} ] - although this isn't storing objects as child documents, it would provide you with a way of finding a key (or part of) and or a value using an index. food for thought